# Firebase databaste structure advice

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need some advice on how to structure my database in order to query it correctly. From what I've understood the structure of the database is everything, but I am not sure I am using it correctly.

Basically my app is supposed to retrive data from an api and display that in a listview. Every item (newspost) in the listview can have comments from firebase users.

So I have "NewsPost" , "User" and "Comment" models that looks like this.'

```
NewsPost.class

private String id;
private String date;
private String title;
private String commentsNumber;
private List<Comment> comments;
private String imageUrl;

User.class
private String userName;
private String userAvatar;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String eMail;

Comment.class
private UUID uuid;
private String postId;
private String message;
private String postDate;
private String userAvatar;
private String userName;
```

So this is how I tried to store it:

[image: Firebase data structure]

AND this is how I try to get the comments when a user clicks to read the comments for the specific newsPostItem in the listView with the newsPostId as a query param.

```
public void getComments(String postId) {

comments = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = databaseReference.child("comments").orderByChild(postId).equalTo(postId);
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot issue : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Comment comment = issue.getValue(Comment.class);
                        comments.add(comment);
                    }
                    Log.d("GETCOMMENTS", "SNAPSHOT EXISTS");
                    view.onCommentsLoaded(comments);
                }

                else{
                    view.onCommentsLoaded(comments);
                    Log.d("GETCOMMENTS", "SNAPSHOT NOT EXISTS");
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                view.onCommentsLoaded(comments);
                Log.d("GETCOMMENTS", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

My Question is, amidoinitrite?

I got a firebase downloaded limit for this month warning (10 GB) which shouldn't happen because I am the only user right now.

Any help is appreciated!

Sidenote: The userAvatar is stored in a byte[] in the database, no good?

Comment: Have you managed to get the desired data?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes and no. If I use a query the snapshot doesn't exist. If I use the dbref then I get the comments, but it complains about large sized requests from the firebase db. Something is obviously badly structures since I've used almost 10 GB of download within a month for ONE user...

Answer (score 0):

When using Firebase, there are a few rules that we need to keep in mind. In your particular case, i recomand you using denormalization and to change the database to be as flatten as possible. For a better understanding, i recomand you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). Because Firebase Realtime Database cannot query over multiple properties, it ussaly involves duplication data. So this things are normal when it comes to Firebase. In your particular case, i recomand you doing both things.

I also recomand you read this post, [Structuring your Firebase Data correctly for a Complex App](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data). It's very well explained and will help you take the best decision.

You need to know that there is no perfect sturcture for a database. You need to structure your database in a way that allows you to read/write data very easily and in a very efficient way. If you don't know yet, Firebase has launched a new product named [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). Realtime Database does not scale automatically while the new Firestore does.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are adding "NewsPostID" as root node inside "comments".
This structure will consume more storage size because every new comments is added as new root inside "comments" node.

Suppose we wants to query that : Specific user's all comments for any single date. so, in this case current structure is complex to apply query.

You can change structure like :

```
"comments" 
     -"userEmail"
            - "NewPostDate"
                       - "NewpostID:15478"
                                       -KHZzTwazaSd (this is random id)
                                          -"message: hey.."  
                                          -"postDate: Date + 12:10PM"  
                                       -KHZzTwazaSd (this is random id)
                                          -"message: Nice post.."  
                                          -"postDate: Date + 12:22PM"  
                       - "NewpostID:54478"
                                       -KHZzTwazaSd (this is random id)
                                          -"message: Nice day"  
                                          -"postDate: Date + 10:45PM"
```

You can get all user related details from user table using "userEmail" from "comments". this will decrease node size and also will be helpful to query.